# Android (phonegap) Click on an input triggers different keyboards, randomly

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap application for android.

If you're not familiar with phonegap, just know that it's an app containing a webview, the rest is made of html/js.

I have a normal input, and when I click on it, I have a normal keyboard that is triggered, with a "Go" button on the bottom right corner.

But sometimes, I get a keyboard that only has an "Enter" key on the bottom right corner. This keyboard usually acts weird, and doesn't want to hide.

I can't understand why my inputs trigger different keyboards.. I only want to keep the first one.

[image: good one]

[image: bad one]

Comment: Can post screenshots of both keyboards?

Comment: I can't say why the second keyboard is being triggered, it seems the focus is placed somewhere else. Are you using any Scrolling library? They tend to cause problems on inputs for some reason. Other than that, can you share the html and any javascript related to that input?

Comment: @gameower Yeah you're very right. I'm using iScroll. I know it's a lot of trouble, I'm pretty sure it's coming from it. Yet I couldn't really find anyone having problems related to mine... If you know any fix/good advice, I'd be glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

So iScroll + Android + Form fields don't seem to work well together. I've faced some nasty issues with textbox disappearing, not working properly, keyboards moving the whole page up. Weird stuff.

We solved it by setting `stopPropagation` on `touchstart` on every single textbox/selects/form fields, and it solved our issue.

```
var selectField = document.getElementById('textbox');   
    selectField.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        //updateScrollPosition(this, true);
    }, false);
```

**EDIT**

The other  workaround I can think about is  to override onBeforeScrollStart to prevent scrolling when the touch happens in selected elements(inputs, selects and textAreas were the issue here but you can target anything):

```
iScroll.options.onBeforeScrollStart = function(e) {      

    var target = e.target;


    while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;     
    if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA'){
        e.preventDefault();
     }};

}
```

**EDIT 2**

So neither of the above helped. The same happened to me a while back so I came up with a (horrible) hack to solve that issue. I can't share this piece of code(oh licenses!) but the steps I did were:

- Check if it's android, and the version is lower than 3.0
- Hide your input and replace with a div
- When you click on the div, run a native bit layer that triggers a click on a hidden EditText
- Add a textChangeListener and copy everything to your div and to your input.
- Get really pissed that's the best solution you found and repeatedly bang your keyboard on the desk.

Comment: Tried implementing it, but now I can't even click on the input. Nothing happens when I tap on it.

Comment: Where are you testing it? It won't work if you're running it on a browser but it should work fine on your phone! Which version of android are you using?

Comment: I'm testing it on an android phone. I know touch events don't exist on a browser ;) I don't have input problems on android >=3. I have trouble on 2.3

Comment: I had good results with overriding onBeforeScrollStart too. Maybe it's worth the shot!

Comment: Yeah I was doing this too. :(